# Integer variables not updating in python

Tags: python, pygame

At the start of my code I make two variables

```
WINDOW_WIDTH = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300
```

Later, in def main(), I change them if an event occurs in the following manner

```
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)
            # Here, the integers are supposed to be being changed
            WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = DISPLAY.get_size()
            print("%d, %d" % (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

 drawArena()
```

The print statement below the change indicates that a change has been made. Then in drawArena() I do the following:

```
print("Drawing (%d, %d)" % (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
```

But the window height and window width are unchanged, and have the same values as when first initialized.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to declare the variables as `global` in the code that changes them?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi This fixed it. Thank you. I did not know about this feature of python, as I am new to the language.

Comment: It's considered good style in Python (and most other languages) to avoid using globals when practical, as they interfere with modularity. But using globals for things like window size is tolerable, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to state that these variables are global

```
global WINDOW_HEIGHT,WINDOW_WIDTH
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
            DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'], HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE) # Here, the integers are supposed to be being changed
            WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = DISPLAY.get_size()
            print("%d, %d" % (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

drawArena()
```